# Using locale's date_format in readr

Tags: r, readr

How do I correctly set locale's `date_format` to work with `cols()` from `readr`?

Instead of specifying the date format for every column:

```
df <- read_csv2(my_file,
                col_types = cols(.default = '?',
                                 my_date = col_date(format = '%d.%m.%Y')))
```

I want to specify it once. `cols()`'s documentation says:

> col_date(format = "") [D]: with the locale's date_format.

so I tried:

```
locale(date_format = '%d.%m.%Y')

df <- read_csv2(my_file,
                col_types = cols(.default = '?',
                                 my_date = 'D'))
```

But this throws the warning (received with `problems()`):

```
expected: <chr> date in ISO8601
actual: <chr> 01.01.2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `locale(...)` as a parameter to `read_csv2` like this:

```
library(readr)

data <- "date1; date2
01.01.2000; 30.01.2000
01.12.2000; 25.12.2000"

read_csv2(data, 
          col_types = "DD",
          locale = locale(date_format = '%d.%m.%Y'))
```